# May I safely use the address of a C++ STL vector element? How?

Tags: c++, vector, stl, element

I want to add an element to a C++ STL vector and then return its address. Perhaps that is not "safe" or possible? If it is a reasonable thing to do, I am not having any luck.

```
struct myStruct{...};

myStruct *myMethod() {
    myStruct myS(...);
    myVector.push_back(myS);
    // I cannot get the following line or any variant thereof to compile
    myStruct *foo = myVector.rebegin();  // or .rend()-1; or &myVector.rebegin();   
    return foo; }
```

As I say, is what I want to do illogical or illegal, and if not, how do I do it? I don't want to use the address of myS because it is on the stack, and I can't make it static because I re-parametize it each time through the method.

Thanks,
Charles

Comment: What is the scope of `myVector`? And what do you have against `vector<myStruct>::iterator`?

Comment: @JaMiT's link I think answers my question. I think perhaps I don't want to/"can't" do this because additions to the vector may move things around, so an address could become invalid unpredictably. Agree? Disagree?

Comment: @Beta myVector is at the class level and I have nothing against anything. Doesn't rbegin() for example return a vector<myStruct>::iterator?

Comment: I think I need to re-do the vector as <* myStruct>, allocate a new element, and delete it at end-of-run.

Comment: A copy of the struct in the vector will not do the job -- the caller of the method wants to modify an element of the struct.

Comment: Just because you can doesn't mean you should. If your design requires this then you should probably take a hard look at that and consider revising it. You haven't really said why you need this so I wonder if we're looking at an XY problem.

Comment: Addresses of elements can be invalidated by additions to the vector. And `rbegin()` returns `reverse_iterator`, which is not quite the same as `iterator`. If you want iterators that remain valid after additions, you might consider `list` instead of `vector`.

Comment: @Beta got it, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You want `return &myVector.back();`.

Answer (score 0):

std::vector in C++11 and later have member function named "data()", which does the thing you want

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data

Comment: as i see, you want pointer, not iterator, so data() is for you

Comment: The `data()` member returns the address of the *first* element. The question is looking for the address of the *last* element.

Comment: ok,
 return vec.data() + sizeof(MyStruct)*(vec.size() -1);
-;)

Comment: ... and I don't have C++1. :-(